# C++ if else if not working properly

Tags: c++

I'm new to c++. I tried to run a console application which has two inputs.
This is my code

```
#include <iostream>

#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    string ID;
    double sal_val,com;
    cout<<"Insert fruit ID"<<endl;
    cin >> ID;
    cout<<"You entered"<<ID<<endl;
    cout<<"Insert sale Value"<<endl;
    cin >> sal_val;
    cout<<"You entered"<<sal_val<<endl;

    if(ID =="A"||"a"){
        com=(sal_val*4.5)/100;          
        cout<<"Commission for Apple Rs. " <<com<<endl;}
    else if(ID =="B"||"b"){
        com=(sal_val*5)/100;
        cout<<"Commission for Banana Rs. " <<com<<endl;}
    else if(ID =="O"||"o"){
        com=(sal_val*5.5)/100;
        cout<<"Commission for Orange Rs. " <<com<<endl;}
    else if(ID =="G"||"g"){
        com=(sal_val*6)/100;
        cout<<"Commission for Grapes Rs. " <<com<<endl;}
}
```

When I run this no matter what value I give for the "ID" It gives the result for the first if statement. Every time only this two lines run 
`com=(sal_val*4.5)/100;

cout<<"Commission for Apple Rs. " <<com<<endl;`

Thanks in advice.

Comment: do it like if(ID =="A"||   ID == "a")  . You are doing  if(ID =="A"||"a") Here this is always true because , ID is compared against "A" but not "A" or "a".Here the second condition is "a" which is the address(non- zero).Anything non zero is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this `if(ID =="A"||"a"){`, you should write `if(ID =="A"|| ID == "a"){` because your statements: `if(ID =="A"||"a"){` means **if** (**ID is "A"** or **the ascii of "a"**). The ascii of "a" is bigger than 0, that means it will be read as `true` value in the **if** statement. That's why your statement will be equal with `if(ID =="A"|| true){` which is why only this statement will be executed.

Comment: Actually, the right expression evaluates to a pointer value.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the expression in the first `if` is always true:

```
  ID == "A"  ||  "a"
```

This does not mean

```
  ID == "A"  ||  ID == "a"
```

which is probably what you want instead.  The first expression evaluates the left side of the OR and that may be true or false, but the right side is *always* true:  the expression `"a"` is nonzero, therefore true.

Answer (score 1):

A non zero value with no logical or relational operators in a boolean condition will always return true. So `"a"` in first `if` will always return `true`.That's why only the first `if` gets executed all the time. Modify you if-else-if as given below:

```
if(ID =="A"||ID == "a"){
        com=(sal_val*4.5)/100;          
        cout<<"Commission for Apple Rs. " <<com<<endl;}
    else if(ID =="B"||ID == "b"){
        com=(sal_val*5)/100;
        cout<<"Commission for Banana Rs. " <<com<<endl;}
    else if(ID =="O"||ID == "o"){
        com=(sal_val*5.5)/100;
        cout<<"Commission for Orange Rs. " <<com<<endl;}
    else if(ID =="G"||ID == "g"){
        com=(sal_val*6)/100;
        cout<<"Commission for Grapes Rs. " <<com<<endl;}
```

For comparing a variable with multiple values individual conditions needs to be written in code as written for each of if-else-if construct.

Answer (score 1):

as @user1438832 said in the comments you have to use If(ID=="A"||ID=="a") and follow this format for all your cases

Answer (score 0):

Your problem with `if` and `else if` condition.

```
if(ID =="A"|| ID == "a"){
        com=(sal_val*4.5)/100;
        cout<<"Commission for Apple Rs. " <<com<<endl;}
    else if(ID =="B"||ID == "b"){
        com=(sal_val*5)/100;
        cout<<"Commission for Banana Rs. " <<com<<endl;}
    else if(ID =="O"|| ID == "o"){
        com=(sal_val*5.5)/100;
        cout<<"Commission for Orange Rs. " <<com<<endl;}
    else if(ID =="G"|| ID == "g"){
        com=(sal_val*6)/100;
        cout<<"Commission for Grapes Rs. " <<com<<endl;}
```